# How to concatenate strings from a series of lists where some elements may be blank

Tags: python, list, concatenation

I have some code that produces a list of strings from a spreadsheet, iteratively in a loop. Each time through the loop, some of the strings may be empty. So for example, the list might be `['John', '']` the first time, `['Jane', 'foo']` the second time, `['Josh', '']` the third time etc.

I want to concatenate only the non-empty strings with a separator, so that e.g. `['Jane', 'foo']` becomes `'Jane - foo'`, but `['Josh', '']` becomes `'Josh'` (not `'Josh - '`).

I tried:

```
if '' in list[:1]:
 lines = [
  list[0]
 ]
else:
 lines = [
  list[0] + ' - ' + list[1]
 ]
```

but it seems that the `if` condition is never satisfied, so I get

```
John -
Jane - foo
Josh -
```

What is wrong with the code, and how can I fix it?

Comment: `'-'.join(filter(None, your_list))`

Comment: you wrote `if '' in list[:1]:` but i think you want `if '' in list[1:]:`. also, you shouldn't name your variables `list`, that shadows the builtin `list`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I [edit]ed the question to show how to ask it properly. The most important thing to note is that this is **not a discussion forum** - so please don't talk about yourself, and please try to describe the problem clearly, accurately and **directly** (i.e.: skip context unless it's *needed in order to understand the problem*). There is nothing wrong with simple questions here, but it's [expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to look for existing versions of the question first, or at least something that's close enough to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method and a comprehension with if condition:

Also avoid using `list` as a variable name it shadows the built in type [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list).

```py
my_lists = [['John', ''], ['Jane', 'foo'], ['Josh', '']]

for line in my_lists:
    print(' - '.join(s for s in line if s))  # empty strings are falsy

# prints
# John
# Jane - foo
# Josh
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems I found in your code.
The first one is that you check if '' is in a string - this will always be true, because the empty string is in all strings:

```
'' in 'hello'
```

returns

```
True
```

So instead you have to check if the second element is equal to the empty string:

```
list[1] == ''
```

The second problem is that you currently return all the elements before the element on position 1, not the element on position 1 itself (string from column B):

```
list = ['Jane', 'foo']
list[:1]
```

returns

```
'Jane'
```

So to fix both issues, you can adjust your code like this:

```
def concat_list_elements(list):
  if list[1] == '':
    lines = [list[0]]
  else:
    lines = [list[0] + ' - ' + list[1]]
  return lines

list_of_lists = [['John', ''],['Jane', 'foo'],['Josh', '']]
overall_list = []

for list in list_of_lists:
  overall_list.append(concat_list_elements(list))

print(overall_list)
```

This then returns

```
[['John'], ['Jane - foo'], ['Josh']]
```